# Can I make a table row appear on another xml file in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, tablelayout

[I want clicked rows to show up here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYBmb.png)

Hello, I am trying to create an app that displays information in a table layout in android studio. One row of the table displays all info for one person. I want to be able to click multiple people and have them show up in a separate menu on another page to compare them. I am unsure how to do this, does anyone know how? Thanks.

Comment: Can you add an image / example showing what you are looking for?

Comment: Just updated with pic